# Как объединить два массива по одинаковым значениям разных ключей?

Tags: php

Как объединить два массива по одинаковым значениям ключа `@kid:=d.kind_id` и `@kind_id`?

**Чтобы из**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 172
    [sn] => Замена блока питания (платы, трансформатора)
    [@kid:=d.kind_id] => 2
)
```

**и второго**

```
Array
(
    [term_id] => 15
    [name] => Кондиционер
    [kind_id] => 2
)
```

Получился один массив, но при условии, указанные ключи совпадают по своим значениям.

Comment: я так понимаю - это результат запроса. так добавьте в нем ``as kind_id``

Comment: @splash58 да, это результаты распечатки массивов в цикле. Не совсем понимаю, как использовать в данном случае конструкцию `as kind_id`

Comment: господи, ну какая проблема перебирать один массив и искать совпадение в другом? А найдя - записать в первый? Какой конкретно шаг вызывает затруднения? Как перебрать массив?

Comment: @Ипатьев не могу понять, как искать совпадения по разным ключам

Comment: Во-первых, ТАК И НАДО ПИСАТЬ. А не тупо повторять один и тот же вопрос. Во-вторых, КАКАЯ РАЗНИЦА, разные ключи, или одинаковые? Вас же интересует ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, при чем здесь ключ? Какая проблема перебирать второй массив и сравнивать значение элемента name?